# PHP Slim CORS issue on browser

Tags: php, http, http-headers, cors, slim

I have a backend in PHP with slim 3, and when testing a POST endpoint with postman it works
perfectly, but when testing when using it with my frontEnd simple JS with AXIOS I stumble with a  CORS error, even though the right header is present ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/formBe/public/form' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
 return $response
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS')
        ->withStatus(200);
```

I have a GET endpoint with same headers and it works.

Any help is appreciated! :D

Comment: I havent used Slim 3, but back when I used Slim 1, we had to an "options" route in order to handle the CORS OPTIONS request sent before the actual ajax request. IE: `$app->options('.*', static function () {}); // this route is needed for the ajax CORS OPTIONS header above to work properly` It could be that Slim 3 needs something similar

Comment: Yeah, see [the docs here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html) where they seem to document the same sort of requirement. Do you have such an options route set up in your app?

Comment: @WesleySmith I had it before, then removed, then added it again, and nothing seems to do the trick, and its weird cause I have a GET route with the same headers and it works fine :(

Comment: In the chrome browser's network tab you should be able to see the ajax request as 2 separate lines, one for the OPTIONS request, and a second for the actual ajax call, they should show the "method" as OPTIONS and POST, whcih one specifically does this error show up for?

Comment: @WesleySmith I dont see the OPTIONS request in red, with the error message in the console. :(

Comment: If you look at the console, there should be a "Network" tab, that will show all the requests made by the browser, NOTE: thee dev console must be open when the request is made or you wont see it there